# Closure of equivalence relations problem at the end

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

The question is "Use Warshall’s Algorithm to find the transitive closure of the relation {(a, c), (b, d), (c, a), (d, b), (e, d)} on the set {a, b, c, d, e}."

My matrix at the end is:
( 1 0 1 0 0 )
( 0 1 0 1 0 )
( 1 0 1 0 0 )
( 0 1 0 1 0 )
( 0 1 0 1 0 )

However, I did some code to do the Warshall's Algorithm and got the exact same output save for there being a 1 at (e,e). How do I get that?

[My work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02I9f.jpg)

Comment: $e$ does not need to be related to $e$ for this to be transitive.  Note that in your example $e$ is never the second entry in any pair.  Perhaps you were accidentally thinking of the *equivalence closure* rather than transitive closure.  You mention "*closure of equivalence relations*" in your title... but neither the relation you mention nor the transitive closure of the relation you mention will be an equivalence relation.

Comment: "*However, I did some code to do the Warshall's Algorithm*"... without seeing more details, I can't tell you what you did wrong there... but note at least that if talking about adding together matrices... do not consider the matrix to the zeroth power... when considering paths do not consider paths of length zero... take care of null pointer exceptions and the like... there are many ways you could have done things wrong and it is unclear what specifically you did wrong beyond that the (e,e) pair need not appear.

Comment: Are they not equivalence relations? It's what my teacher has it listed as.

So there's no reason for there to be (e,e) at the end? That makes sense to me, though I wanted to verify that. Is there a way for me to send more details?

Comment: An equivalence relation must be transitive, but it must also be symmetric and it must also be reflexive.  Just finding the transitive closure of a relation does not also make it reflexive or symmetric.  The transitive closure of a relation is merely the smallest relation that is transitive which contains the original relation, but as seen here might still be missing certain pairs necessary to make it reflexive or symmetric.

Comment: I see what you mean, that makes sense. I suppose a title change is in need then.

Comment: I put my work in the original post through an edit, does everything check out there?

Comment: Yes, but what I was talking about missing information was "*I did some code to do...*" since that is where the error is

Comment: I see, well I'm not sure I can send the code myself, but I found some code online that seems to output similar results from this link: https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-warshall-algorithm/#google_vignette

Comment: That is getting outside the scope of this site, but line 22 of the linked code `tc[i][i] = true`  This shouldn't be there and is where the reflexive closure is accidentally also being added.